# How not to lose Auto Generated Value = TRUE when dragging table from server explorer into visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer

when I drag a table from the server explorer to the *.dbml file using the Visual Studio 2013 designer, the property "Auto Generated Value" is always false, even if a formula for a default value was entered within the SQL database, for example (getdate()) for a datetime variable.

So far I only found an answer from 2008 (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51de24a4-eb4b-45cf-9835-b3568e93121a/auto-generated-value-and-auto-sync-questions?forum=linqprojectgeneral) where the answer was that this is not implemented, and I am woundering if it is possible now.

Many thanks in advance!